# Internet Explorer ignoring CSS font size (but not everywhere)

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, font-size

I have been trying to give my (wordpress-powered) website a standard look and feel across all platforms and browsers. I think I'm almost there, but have a weird problem with Internet Explorer.

The font size looks completely fine on everything except IE, where it is huge. I understand this is a fairly common problem do to IE/CSS quirks, but I have not been able to solve it using any of the fixes found in this forum or elsewhere (for example I've changed all font sizes to .em rather than px).

I know there's a number of errors when you use the validator, but I don't see any errors there that seem to be causing it.

To make matters worse, everything renders perfectly when viewing an individual post (and only posts- it's still weird when you see a page). I've tried going through the html line-by-line to try to figure out what's on the single.php that isn't on anything else (and vice versa), but have come up short. IE also seems unresponsive to pretty much any changes I make to the font.

My site is http://andrewkurjata.ca if anyone is able to figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you indicate which bit is "wrong"? When i open the given url in internet explorer 9 (9.0.8112). Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view Source then you will find following Code

```
<h1> 
                <h1><a href="http://andrewkurjata.ca/blog">AndrewKurjata.ca</a> 
</h1>
```

Now here you have started two < h1 > and ending only one...
In Firefox and other browser it is closing first < h1 > automatically. But in IE8 it is not closing.

So inner < h1 > is taking 160% of outer < h1 > giving you bigger size issue

**Remove one h1 to solve**

Comment: +1 HTML and CSS validation are the first step. If those don't validate, the results will be unpredictable.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I can't believe it was such a simple fix that I just kept overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CSS reset might work with you http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/